# How to migrate an online angular script to local server?

Tags: angularjs

Hi I'm trying to make an offline version of this page:
https://u-he.com/tools/microtuning/ the script is writtin with Angular JS how do I do that?

I saved the page control-s and copied the file to the local server I'm running.
And then I browsed the local ip. the page opened but I get repeated notes ng-repeat shows up as multiple boxes instead of 1 box that edits the same note but in different octaves.

How do I solve this problem please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inspect the front-end code in your browser console. In Firefox it's in the section called "Debugger", in Chrome it's called "Sources". If you use Safari, you need to enable Developer mode first.

Once you have the appropriate view, just click on `u-he.com -> tools/microtuning/ -> index`

[image]

Hopefully it goes without saying that you shouldn't use large swaths of another person's code without at least giving appropriate credit, or better yet getting the developer's permission, unless there is an explicit open-source license.

Comment: "u-he.com -> tools/microtuning/ -> index" - this is not visible in chrome when clicking "sources".

Comment: You solved my problem this is my first day with angular... thanks for your time and effort. I copied the code from sources into an editor and saved it. But can you give me a brief explanation on why it worked by copying the code and not by saving the page control-s.

Comment: That's just a text representation. Let me see if I can add a screenshot to my original answer

Comment: Well, Angular is a Javascript library that lets you write custom HTML and inject that with code. Essentially, when you load the page, the Angular JS library re-writes its templates as standard HTML. So if you just look at the regular source code, that has already been translated. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Oh that totally makes sense! So all the objects from ng-repeat got re-written in the HTML when I saved it 12 times!... Thank you for taking the time!